# Function constructor and eval

Tags: jquery

Line 576 of jQuery 1.7rc1 is:

`return (new Function( "return " + data ))();`

Now jshint complains with the warning

> The Function constructor is eval.

What does this error mean? Why did the jQuery people write this line the way it is?

Comment: There is no set of rules how to write code. JSHINT/JSLINT is a set of guidelines for good and proper code construction. Do you get an error, or is out of interest? :)

Comment: Well the jQuery code produces a jshint warning. It's out of interest that I'm asking here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [`eval` is evil](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx) and the `Function` constructor uses `eval` to create the new `Function`, jshint doesn't like it.  JQuery is using it to parse JSON for older browsers that don't natively support `JSON.parse()`.